# Is modification of dependency, of a dependency mentioned in makefile, not recognized by make?

Tags: c++, makefile, virtual

In my code, I have used three classes. All the classes are in separate files. And I am using `Makefile` to compile and link them.
See the implementation below:

```
class Medicine 
{ 
   int a;
}

class Pain:public Medicine 
{
   int b;
}

class Comb:public Pain   
{
    string salt,com;
}
```

All classes have just parameterized constructors, virtual destructors and a function with same name `call()`, in all the three classes.
And `call()` is like

```
call()
{
     cout<<"You are in class the_name_of_the_class"<<endl;
}
```

The code of `main.cpp` goes like:

```
int main()
{       
    Medicine *p[2];
    p[0]= new Comb("Salt","Com",2,110);
    p[1]= new Comb("SALT","COM",1,100);

    p[0]->call();

    delete p[0];
    delete p[1];
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this program, I got the expected output. But when I changed the Medicine::call() to be a virtual function, and again used `make` command, it says all files are up to date. As I have modified `medicine.h`, so `make` should created new version of `medicine.o`. Why is it considering older `medicine.o`as updated when I have modified `medicine.h`?

The Makefile goes like this:

```
using .PHONY:clean
OBJ:=medicine.o pain.o comb.o main.o
SOU:=medicine.cpp pain.cpp comb.cpp main.cpp

main:$(OBJ)
        g++ -o $@ $^

%.o:%.cpp
        g++ -c -o $@ $<

clean:
        rm *.o main
```

If you want to see implementation of medicine.h,

```
class Medicine
{
    int cost;

 public:

    int getCost();
    void setCost(int);

    Medicine();
    Medicine(int);
    Medicine(Medicine &a);
    virtual string getCompany(){};
    virtual string getSalt(){};
    virtual  ~Medicine ();
    virtual void call();
};
```

This `medicine.h` I have included in `medicine.cpp`, where all these functions are defined.

Comment: You didn't tell `make` that `medicine.o` depends on `medicin.h`. So how do you think it shall know that??? Btw, this has nothing to do with the content of that file (implying that the title of your question is highly misleading).

Comment: `make` does not scan C++ files for dependencies. You must manually list the dependencies (headers etc.) of each file for `make` to determine whether that file is up-to-date

Comment: medicine.cpp has included medicine.h, which means it is dependent on medicine.h. That way, medicine.o depend on medicine.h also.

Comment: For a build system that automatically discovers both dependencies and targets, see [tup](http://gittup.org/tup/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your makefile doesn't have the dependencies for your header files to the source files, so it doesn't know that you need to recompile "x.cpp" when "y.h" has changed (because "y.h" is included by "x.cpp").

You can fix that by having rules like:

```
medicine.o : medicine.cpp medicine.h
```

However, as the number of source files get larger, and the relationship of headers to source gets more complex, you are going to forget/leave out some header files that you actually need - this will ALWAYS happen.

What I usually do is something like this:

```
SOU = medicine.cpp pain.cpp comb.cpp main.cpp
... 

main:$(OBJ) .depends

...

.depends: $(SOU)
     g++ -MM $(SOU) > $@

include .depends
```

What this does is to let the compiler generate the rules into a file `.depends` - that way, you don't "forget" to fix it up when you update a file somewhere.

**Edit:**
For large projects, using a single dependency file is a poor idea, because every time a .cpp file is changed, the compiler will have to sort out all the dependencies for every file in the project. But for a small hobby project it's fine. For large projects, one would take the extra penalty of having lots of `.depends` files (one per source file, probably in a `depends` directory).

Comment: I accept your solution. <br/> But I want to know for knowledge that,  according to what I read is, when a file is modified, make becomes aware of it by seeing the last modification time of both object and .cpp file. So, when .cpp file has included medicine.h, and medicine.h is modified, so wont the medicine.cpp be considered updated. If yes, why?

Comment: That is exactly the point: Make does not know that `medicine.cpp` is related to `medicine.h` - so when you modify `medicine.h`, the file `medicine.cpp` is not in itself modified, and make goes "medicine.o is newer than medicine.cpp, so no work to do here". Make needs to know ALL the relationships between files.

Comment: Refering to your edit: So, can we have multiple Makefiles also?

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple makefiles, and include one into another. Or use `$(MAKE) -f another.mk` or some such.

Comment: @Smith: Yes, but before you go that route you should investigate alternatives. `make` is really 1970's level technology.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Can you please tell a link from where I can read more about this type of makefiles? I tried to google, but there is so much material and nothing good for a beginner. I just know the makefile I have shown in my code above. So, can you give some guidelines or website for simple understanding of makefile?

Comment: @Smith: I don't have a "beginners guide to Makefiles", I'm afraid - I have been using Make since the late 1980's or so. I use the gnu make documentation (http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) to look things up. A quick search found this "beginners guide", which seems pretty good from a quick scan: 
http://www.linuxforu.com/2012/06/gnu-make-in-detail-for-beginners/

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `medicine.o` only depends on `medicine.cpp`, not on `medicine.h`. So you have to modify your rules to provide that missing dependency. It has absolutely nothing to do with "virtualness".

You might also want to add the Makefile itself as a dependency, so if you change it and run make, things get re-built.

To clarify, this generic rule:

```
%.o:%.cpp
    g++ -c -o $@ $<
```

means that any `something.o` depends on `something.cpp` only, and should be built with the following command:

```
g++ -c -o something.o something.cpp
```

i.e. `$@` is the target name and `$<` is the first dependency.

the format is

```
target : <dependencies>
    command
```

Comment: But medicine.cpp has included medicine.h, which means it is dependent on medicine.h. That way, medicine.o depend on medicine.h also. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Smith: you are wrong in that make does not care about the content of the files; all the dependencies it knows are those you precised in the makefile, and you never told it that `medicine.o` depended on `medicine.h`, thus `make` assumes it does not. (I would understand if you think it is stupid, frankly Makefile are serviceable but far from being easy to use)

Comment: @Smith it depends on it, but the makefile needs *you* to give it the dependencies (usually, *you* can be replaced by some clever script or is done automatically by an IDE or build system). `make` does not figure out the dependencies by itself.

Comment: What I read is, when a file is modified, make becomes aware of it by seeing the last modification time of both object and .cpp file. So, when .cpp file has included medicine.h, and medicine.h is modified, so wont the medicine.cpp be considered updated. If yes, why?

Comment: @Smith what happens is that, for a given target, `make` checks the dependencies according to the rule for that target. So when you ask for `medicine.o`, it checks `medicine.cpp` **only**, because you haven't told it that `medicine.cpp` depends on `medicine.h`. You have to add `medicine.h` to the list of dependencies of `medicine.o`.

Answer (score 1):

`make` is not language-aware, so yes, make does not know whether a function is virtual or not; actually it does not even know what C++ is and that there are functions there.

`make` operates in terms of targets and dependencies, and those have to be specified explicitly. Here, the rule to make an object does not include any `.h` file in the dependencies and thus it deduces that `.8` files are unused for the target.

It is actually quite difficult to get the proper set of *transitive* includes needed to build one `.cpp` file. There are scripts to assist such as [`make_depend.pl`](http://www.filewatcher.com/p/cxref-1.6d.tgz.415744/cxref-1.6d/contrib/make_depend.pl.html).

Answer (score 0):

The working of `make` is like this:
It checks the latest modification time of the dependency (`medicine.cpp` for eg) and then check the latest modification time of `medicine.cpp` when `medicine.o` was created. If both are same, then its not recompiled, otherwise recompiled. In my case, `medicine.h` was modified, but the latest modification time of `medicine.cpp` remain unchanged. And that's why `make` was unable to detect this and not recompiled `medicine.cpp`.